# Trying to get clicked on a RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a recyclerView in  a Fragment, i also implement the onItemClickListener in the adapter.
now i need to give the click the action in the recyclerView in the Fragment but i can't do it.
Hope you can help me to figure out it. I appreciate it.

First this is the Adapter:

```
    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    public TextView textName;
    public TextView textAddress;
    public ImageView imageView;
    private Place place;



    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        textName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
        textAddress = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.placeAddress);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imagePlace);

    }

    public void bind(Place place) {
        this.place = place;
        textName.setText(place.getName());
        textAddress.setText(place.getAdress());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        return false;
    }



    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        PlaceAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
        void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
        Place sendToMap();
    }
}
```

then i have the Fragment:

```
 public class FragmentNearMe extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    public static final String SEARCH_RESULT_ACTION="SEARCH_RESULT_ACTION";
    private int aroundMe;
    private PlaceAdapter adapter;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private SearchBrodcastReciver searchBrodcastReciver;
    private EditText searchFild;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private ImageView iconPlace;
    private Context context;

    public void setLatLng(LatLng latLng) {
        if (this.latLng == null) {
            getView().findViewById(R.id.location_warning).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchFild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        this.latLng = latLng;
    }

    public static FragmentNearMe newInstance(int around) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, around);
        FragmentNearMe fragment = new FragmentNearMe();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        aroundMe = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        searchBrodcastReciver=new SearchBrodcastReciver();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_me, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView listPlaces = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.placesList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        adapter = new PlaceAdapter(new ArrayList<Place>());
        listPlaces.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        listPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);

        searchFild= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
        ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(searchBrodcastReciver, new IntentFilter(SEARCH_RESULT_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(searchBrodcastReciver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String placeName= searchFild.getText().toString();
        if(placeName != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyIntentService.class);
            intent.putExtra(MyIntentService.KEY_PLACE, placeName);
            intent.putExtra(MyIntentService.KEY_RADIUS, 5);
            intent.putExtra(MyIntentService.KEY_LOCATION, latLng);
            getActivity().startService(intent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext() , "place not exsist" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public class SearchBrodcastReciver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(SEARCH_RESULT_ACTION)){
                PlaceLogic placeLogic= new PlaceLogic(getActivity());
                adapter.setPlaces(placeLogic.getAllPlaces());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *but i can't do it*? What is your problem?

Comment: i meant i need to clicked on an item in a the recyclerView, so i need to implement the click in the fragment. and i dont know how to do it.

Comment: follow my answer it will work

Comment: Use Interfaces and Custom listeners

Answer (score 1):

copy this inside you Adapter

`public interface OnClickListner {
    void setOnItemClick(int postion, View view);
}`

then create an instance `OnClickListner onClickListner ;`

then create a setter `public void setOnClickListner(OnClickListner onClickListner ) {
        this.onClickListner = onClickListner ;
    }`

now in OnBind

```
 holder.myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickListner .setOnItemClick(position,view);
        }
    });
```

then in Your fragment
paste these

```
adapter.setOnClickListner(this);
```

then implement method and perform action

Comment: This is very right approach to create custom listener @liad iluz go ahead with above example.

Comment: accept answer by clicking Check button. so it might helpful to others @liadiluz

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick on the layout itemLayoutView it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the click listener

```
public static interface ClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerItemListner implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private AtInfamaCenter.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerItemListner(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final AtInfamaCenter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Then use it this way in the onActivityCreated method

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new  MyActivity.RecyclerItemListner(getActivity(), recyclerView, new MyActivity.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

           //Code when item is clicked
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, final int position) {

// code when item is long clicked

            }
        }));
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding